# VS says "You have 1 deprecated package versions installed", but which one?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, deprecated

Got the yellow rectangle with the following message:

> You have 1 deprecated package versions installed

[image]

How can I find out out which one?

So far I've tried:

- scrolling through my dozens of packages, hoping some of them will be flagged as depreciated
- seeing Package Manager Console
- seeing Output: Package Manager.

Comment: Have you read https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-packages-on-nuget-org/#client-experience? It suggests you should see the same warning triangle by the version of the relevant package.

Comment: Many thx. this is an answer in case you are willing to post it, and extra bonus the `dotnet.exe list package --deprecated` part

Answer (score 4):

Run the command:

> dotnet list ["path"] package --deprecated

Comment: Ran command with --deprecated and --vulnerable, and even though the icon shows up in Nuget Package manager, command line commands return no deprecated or vulnerable packages

Comment: @dkimbell13 I think the icons you see are either deprecated or vulnerable. The command issues instead 'and' operators. I think that's why there is nothing returned in the command line.